# Поиск по регулярному выражению SQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

В базе есть строка например `ул. Одесская 177, д.78 корп. 2`. Нужно при запросе `одес 78` получать эту строку.

```
$str = str_replace(" ", ".+", $str);
Base::run("SELECT * FROM city WHERE address REGEXP ?", [$str])->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Результат: 0

Comment: Пробовали использовать лексемы и хранить такие строки в векторе (например ts_vector для postgresql)?

Comment: строку 'одес 78' разбить с помощью explode. Далее  делайте выборку с помощью оператора LIKE: SELECT * FROM `city` WHERE `adress` LIKE '%одес%78%'; Данные в LIKE подставляете из полученного с помощью explode массива.

Comment: @МаксМаксимус да, делал так. Это работает если строка с одним пробелом.

Comment: @МаксМаксимус хотя да, работает, я не заметил это. Вы правы, я невнимательно смотрел, спасибо. Можете дать ответ полноценный.

Comment: а какие еще варианты интересуют? пример напишите.

Comment: WHERE adress LIKE '%одес% and adress LIKE %78% - так будет работать возможно выбирая лишнее, но зато найдет, если адрес будет записан в европейском формате - в обратном порядке

Comment: Простой вариант заменить все пробелы на `%` и использовать `LIKE`